# Is meth widely consumed in North Korea?

Tags: recreational-drugs, north-korea

Just found this image on [9gag](http://9gag.com/gag/avgBEdd/some-trivia-about-north-korea) :

[image: A claim about meth use in North Korea]

"Offered as casually as a cup of tea" is not precise (is tea often consumed in North Korea?), so my question is:

**Is meth consumed more often in North Korea than in most countries in the world?**

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that it's been claimed that North Korea partly finances its government through selling drugs. Apparently (although I don't have any evidence to back this up) there's quite a lot of drug use just outside of the country as a result.

Comment: Did some reading: this article (http://www.vice.com/read/north-korea-crystal-meth-drugs-diplomats-nathan-thompson) has some info on this subject.